# JavaFX custom CellFactory with Decimal only input

Tags: regex, javafx-2, tablecell

I have created a custom TableCell cellfactory. I want it to accept only Decimal input (numeric & only one dot(.)). Below is the code for replaceText & replaceSelection but it doesnt allow me to enter anything.

```
        @Override
        public void replaceText(int start, int end, String text) {
            if (text.matches("/^\\d*\\.?\\d*$/")) {
                super.replaceText(start, end, text);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void replaceSelection(String text) {
            if (text.matches("/\\d*\\.?\\d*$/")) {
                super.replaceSelection(text);
            }
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java regexes aren't surrounded by '/'. Depending on the actual behavior you want, you need something like

```
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^\\d*\\.?\\d*$");
final TextField tf = new TextField() {
   @Override
   public void replaceText(int start, int end, String text) {
       String newText = getText().substring(0, start)+text+getText().substring(end);
        if (pattern.matcher(newText).matches()) {
            super.replaceText(start, end, text);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void replaceSelection(String text) {
        int start = getSelection().getStart();
        int end = getSelection().getEnd();
        String newText = getText().substring(0, start)+text+getText().substring(end);
        if (pattern.matcher(newText).matches()) {
            super.replaceSelection(text);
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex has a flaw. It can even match with empty string as you are making everything optional in there.

```
text.matches("/^\\d*\\.?\\d*$/")
```

So Change it like below:

```
text.matches("/^\\d+(\\.\\d+)?$/")
```

Here it means mandatory digits at the begin(`^\\d+`), and then optional dot and digits after(`(\\.\\d+)?$`).

Comment: Don't you need to test the result of the replacement against the regex, instead of the text that's being passed into the method? Something like `String newText = getText().substring(start)+text+getText.substring(end); if (newText.matches("...")) { super.replace(start, end, text);}`

Answer (score -1):

You are replacing the text afterwards. I suppose it would be better to not change the text directly and listen to KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED on the parent (with EventFilter).

You get the event then and check the character if it is numeric or not. You consume the event if you don't want it to show in the input.

Comment: This is not a good approach. You need to look at the whole text, not at each keystroke individually. How would you use this approach to prevent invalid input such as "123.456.789"? What about interfering with ctrl-C and ctrl-V, and other predefined key combinations? The mechanism proposed by the OP doesn't "replace the text afterwards" anyway, it vetoes changes if they are invalid.

Comment: @James_D, you can get the text as a whole in the handler, so I don't see any problem. As well, you can filter ctrl + key strokes, it is in the key event. I personally prefer this approach, as it doesn't depend on JavaFX implementation: the TextField is a black box and it will not change if the TextField API changes.

Comment: In general, I prefer not to subclass for the same reasons, but in this case there's an enormous amount of functionality you'd have to replicate. How would you deal with the built-in context menu that allows the user to paste text into the text field? There's no keystroke involved in that...